# Force on a Magnetic Dipole due to Another Dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, magnetic-fields, dipole-moment

I'm trying to find the force on a magnetic dipole $m_2(r,0,0)$ on the x-axis due to the magnetic field $\vec B_1$ produced by a another dipole $m_1(0,0,0)$ which is at the origin. Both magnetic points $\vec m_1$ and $\vec m_2$ point in the positive x-direction

I've made the assumption that a dipole can be modelled as a small current loop and therefore has the field:

$$\vec B_1 = \mu_0 \frac {m_1}{4\pi r^3} (2\cos \theta \hat r + \sin \theta \hat \theta)$$

The formula to find the force is $\vec F = \nabla(\vec m \cdot \vec B)$, now in order to use this I decided to convert $\vec B_1$ into cartesian coordinates using:
$$\hat r = \sin \theta \cos \theta \hat x +\sin \theta \sin \phi \hat y + \cos \theta \hat z $$
$$\hat \theta = \cos \theta \cos \phi \hat x + \cos \theta \sin \phi \hat y - \sin \theta \hat z$$

Since I'm looking for $\vec m_2 \cdot \vec B_1$ and $\vec m_2 = m_2 \hat x$ only $B_x$ is relevant which using the conversion I found to be: $B_x = \mu_0 \frac {m_1}{4\pi r^3} (2\cos \theta (\sin \theta \cos \phi) + \sin \theta (\cos \theta \cos \phi)) = 3\mu_0 \frac {m_1}{4\pi r^3} \sin \theta \cos \theta \cos \phi$

Now from here I get unsure of how to continue, do I take the Cartesian Gradient or Spherical? I would think Cartesian since I did the scalar product in Cartesian. But since I don't have a function of $x, y$ or $z$ this would yield $0$. Using the Spherical Polar Gradient I get a large expression which I don't believe is correct:
$$\vec F_{21} = \mu_0 \frac {m_1m_2} {4\pi r^4} (-9 \sin \theta \cos \theta \cos \phi \hat r + 3\cos \phi \cos2 \theta \hat \theta + -3\cos \theta \sin \phi \hat \phi)$$
Using a different formula [Forces between two magnetic dipoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles) I get:
$$\vec F_{21} = -3\mu_0 \frac {m_1m_2} {2\pi r^4} \hat x$$
Which looks more correct since it is almost identical to a result from Griffith's which deals with a similar problem but with the two dipoles on the z-axis. I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what is wrong with my original approach. I know I can get the right answer just using the formula but I would really like to know why the first one doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

I've realised the reason why the method does not work is because the expression for $\vec B_1$ I was using was only valid for a dipole with a magnetic moment orientated in the positive $\hat z$ direction.

Comment: If θ is the angle between the dipole moment and the x axis, then it should be zero in your first equation.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've realised that the expression I have for $\vec B1$ is only valid for a dipole with it's magnetic moment orientated in the positive $\hat z$ direction.